# java swing как добавить boxlayout

Tags: java, swing

пишу программу которая рассчитает сопротивление резисторов подключенных параллельно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сейчас имею это и оно выводит  две кнопки в центре

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){


            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

            }
        });
    }


}


package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public MainWindow() throws HeadlessException{

        setTitle("ВЫчисляшка сопротивления из кучи резисторов");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocation(300,200);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //создаем панель с кнопками по  grid табличный менеджер в пнели указана 1 строка и 2 колонки под кнопки
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,5,0));
        panel1. add(new JButton("ОК"));
        panel1. add(new JButton("Отмена"));

        //добавляем панель
        add(panel1);

    }
}
```

у меня два вопроса: как пихать boxLayout и почему все везде создают панели, а у меня просто 
add(panel1);  а должно быть что-то типо panel.add(button) ?

Comment: панель это просто контейнер, возможность сгруппировать компоненты, используйте их на свое усмотрение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Как видим с докумментации, `BoxLayout` используют для построения елементов на каждом новом ряду. Он нам отлично подойдет для левой колонки (текстового поля и лейблов)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Панель это как контейнер (содержащий другие компоненты), который удобно размещать на нужной позиции. Для этого мы можем использовать три панели (можно и с одной, но при большем кол-ве елементов будет нужна панель (проще указать позицию для одной панели, чем нескольких других елементов)), размещенные в один ряд (для этого используем `FlowLayout`).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути у нас такое рассположение объектов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Вычисляшка сопротивления из кучи резисторов");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.getRootPane().setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        // Левая панель
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        // Центральная
        JPanel mid = new JPanel();
        mid.add(new JButton("Button"));

        // Правая панель
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.add(new JLabel("JLabel"));

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        text.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 50));
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        // Добавляю лейблы и выравниваю по левому краю
        JLabel text2 = new JLabel("Text2");
        JLabel text3 = new JLabel("Text3");
        JLabel text4 = new JLabel("Text4");
        text2.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        text3.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        text4.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        left.add(text);
        left.add(text2);
        left.add(text3);
        left.add(text4);

        frame.add(left);
        frame.add(mid);
        frame.add(right);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

По поводу просто add - это добавление в форму.

Добавление BoxLayout

```
 BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout( panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS );
 panel1.setLayout( boxLayout );
```